# Why there is no proper badge for accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, badges, accepted-answer

It struck me recently that it might be a good idea if there were specific badges for users who have provided several accepted answers in a certain amount of time, say in a day or a week. **For instance**, a silver badge for a user that has 5-10 (just for example) accepted answers :) in one day or a gold for more accepted ones in longer periods.

One of the possible advantages is that it encourages users to provide better quality answers and refrain from unproductive contributions.

As you may know the only badges related to accepted answers are followings :

[image]

**So if its not a good idea that badges encourage users to post valuable answers whats your suggestion for such thing?**

Comment: Probably not "in a certain amount of time". 10-15 accepted answers in one day is a pretty big ask.

Comment: Accepted answers provide the largest rep gain per "action" already (Bounties and Association Bonus aside). Do they really need more rewards? Badges requiring a certain amount of accepted answers don't encourage quality. They encourage quantity with just enough quality to get accepted. Basically, those badges encourage mediocrity.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not talking about rep because as you said accepted answer provides more reps i'm talking about encouraging the users to provide better quality answers and refrain from unproductive contributions.

Comment: So why down vote? it's just an idea :)

Comment: @Kasra It's an idea that people disagree with. From the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ah.. yeah i'll edit that tag!

Comment: or, maybe a badge that's based on a "streak" of quality(meaning positively scored) answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I disagree with this suggestion:

Accepted answers provide the largest rep gain per "action" already (Bounties and Association Bonus aside).
Do they really need more rewards?

As you mentioned:
*"One of the possible advantages is that it encourages users to provide better quality answers and refrain from unproductive contributions."*

I don't think this will be the case.

Badges that require a certain amount of accepted answers don't encourage users to post quality answers.
They encourage quantity with just enough quality to get accepted.
Basically, those badges will most likely result in a increase of mediocre answers.

Now, if you want to encourage quality answers, I'd reward users for posting answers that don't get downvoted / removed, for example.

Comment: Yes most likely that badges don't encourage users to post valuable answers but whats your suggestion for such things?

Comment: If there were a good solution to users posting low quality questions / answers, SE would've implemented it already.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Such badges would be more likely encourage people to play at FGITW than to provide good answers to good questions.

Comment: How providing a good solution  to that answers /questions can encourage users?

Comment: @Kasra: What? I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to say.

Comment: Im too with understanding your mean by *good solution*?

Comment: What I mean is: Yes, users posting low quality content is a problem. However, no-one knows how to "fix" the problem. There is no solution to the problem. Sure, we can encourage people to post higher quality posts, but in the end, the user is responsible for the quality of his or her posts. There is no way to "fix" this.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah you are right and i'm agree. I don't say let `fix` this problem my question is more about a suggestion about this problem! and i think its not deserve of 3 down vote O_0

Comment: They'd also discourage looking at questions that already have answers, since that reduces the chances of yours being the one that's accepted. I doubt that people who are currently posting bad content are actually capable of posting really good content, and are just not motivated to do so because there isn't a badge for having answers accepted.

Comment: @Kasra: This problem has been discussed a lot already. Imo, SO's doing quite a lot to get the most out of people, already.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yeah unfortunately you are right *people who are currently posting bad content don't actually capable of posting really good content*

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah i know i just wanted to post a new suggestion that seems its really useless!